# Recording screen and audio on muted PC

Tags: 18.04, sound, audio-recording

Do you know if there is chance to somehow catch audio from one card (for example: skype conversation) and mute my laptop without losing audio?

I would like concurrently record two separate calls (one on Skype another on Discord) and having my laptop muted at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

I typically use `pavucontrol` to direct audio to various devices and to record from selected outputs.  For instance Chrome is playing to my headset, I can go to the Recording tab after starting an Audacity recording and select 'Monitor Of Headset' for the source.  This will tell Audacity to record what is playing in my headset.

Sometimes you need a device to just pipe audio through, this can be achieved with `sudo modprobe snd-dummy` and it will create a virtual audio device.  You can't hear anything that is set to play to it, but you can set things to record whatever is playing to it.

Sometimes you want to hear 2 different audio streams but you only want one to be recorded.  In PulseAudio Preferences there is a 'Simultaneous Output' tab that allows you to add another virtual device that will send the audio to all devices.

For your case, you could create a virtual snd-dummy, set both skype and discord to play the audio to it, and set you recording app to record the monitor of it, you will neither hear the convo nor will they hear you (if that is what you meant by muted).  If you want to hear it as well, you only need to set the recorder to listen to your audio output and you don't need snd-dummy or simultaneous devices.

Note that sometimes the device listed for snd-dummy may be confusing, it may show up as 'Built-in Audio' when you already have one, usually the second one in the list is the snd-dummy.

Another Example:
I want to make a Skype call using a sound board and record it at the same time.  I would setup a virtual snd-dummy to record audio for the Skype mic and set the sound board to play audio to the simultaneous output virtual device, which will play it to my headphones and the virtual snd-dummy device.  Then set Audacity to record the monitor of my headphones, which is playing the soundboard and the skype audio, catching the entire convo.  My actual microphone is not configured in the setup so it is not recorded or heard.